# MySQL multi rows UPDATE

Tags: mysql

How it's possible join into one query:

```
UPDATE products SET products_price='50.0000' where products_id in (SELECT products_id FROM products_description where products_name='Dual 111 HDMI mit USB') LIMIT 1;
UPDATE products SET products_price='36.4900' where products_id in (SELECT products_id FROM products_description where products_name='HYUNDAI 5003') LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could use IF conditions:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

See also: [MySQL UPDATE using IF condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1886928/mysql-update-using-if-condition)

Comment: TNX! it's more simple for me use additional table and use query like this: UPDATE products, importcsv, products_description 
SET products.products_price=importcsv.price, products.products_status=1 
WHERE products_description.products_name=importcsv.brendname
AND products_description.products_id = products.products_id"